# is there a compatible ORM for Windows RT

Tags: .net, entity-framework, sqlite, windows-runtime, sqlite-net

i have tried sqlite-net nuget package for simplifying the work needed to do CRUD operations with sqllite in WindowsStore Apps.Is there a better ORM for sqlliteT?

Answer (score 0):

Define better.

Sqlite-net offers easy queries and LINQ support. But you can also try SQLwinrt (https://sqlwinrt.codeplex.com/) which is another SQLite wrapper for Windows RT / Windows Phone by Andy Wigley. I personally prefer sqlite-net but that's just my opinion. However both will not help you with CRUD  (except for the work with annotations), they do CRUD by default (that's what databases do with records..).